# R package RGL fails to install on a Mac with MRAN

Tags: r, rgl

I'm trying to install rgl because another package needs some element of it. I have XQuartz running on the Mac because I'm using MRAN R. The installation (from CRAN within Rstudio, from the shell in Rstudio and other sources) fails with the following errors.

```
    clang-omp++ -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers  -DHAVE_PNG_H -I/Users/gcn/anaconda/include/libpng16 -I/usr/X11/include -DDarwin -DNO_GL_PREFIX -I/opt/X11/include -DHAVE_FREETYPE -Iext/ftgl -I/opt/X11/include/freetype2 -Iext  -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/External-R-3.3.3/vendor/build/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -I/opt/X11/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native -std=c++11 -c platform.cpp -o platform.o
platform.cpp:38:18: error: no member named 'x' in '_GLKVector3'
      *winX = result.x;
              ~~~~~~ ^
    platform.cpp:39:18: error: no member named 'y' in '_GLKVector3'
      *winY = result.y;
              ~~~~~~ ^
    platform.cpp:40:18: error: no member named 'z' in '_GLKVector3'
      *winZ = result.z;
              ~~~~~~ ^
    platform.cpp:64:18: error: no member named 'x' in '_GLKVector3'
      *objX = result.x;
              ~~~~~~ ^
    platform.cpp:65:18: error: no member named 'y' in '_GLKVector3'
      *objY = result.y;
              ~~~~~~ ^
    platform.cpp:66:18: error: no member named 'z' in '_GLKVector3'
      *objZ = result.z;
```

I also have a version of Rstudio running in an ubuntu instance on AWS and I didn't get these errors when installing. The ubuntu doesn't use MRAN so I suppose that could the source of the problem on the mac, but this page from Microsoft - https://mran.microsoft.com/web/checks/check_results_rgl.html seems to suggest rgl does run with MRAN on a mac.

Comment: You could post the bug to MRAN's Github page, or just use R from CRAN.  I have heard (but have not personally confirmed) that MRAN handles C++ incorrectly, and there are problems with lots of packages that use C++.

Comment: I posted a query at the MRAN Community website a couple of weeks ago and updated it yesterday. No responses. I couldn't find a GitHub page for MRAN. I've been using MRAN for a while now and haven't had any MRAN-specific problems, at least that I could document.

Comment: The Github page I was thinking of was https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-r-open, not exactly MRAN.

Comment: _"Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do that ..."_ -- why not install just rgl from CRAN then?

Comment: The version on CRAN fails (or at least did the last time I tried). I was able to install successfully following the procedure below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have the compiler define `__STRICT_ANSI__` set.  Normally rgl doesn't set that.  The latest version of rgl on R-forge (0.98.13) has this fixed in the platform.cpp file where you saw the error, but there may be other places where problems arise.

You can get the latest version on R-forge.  It is not available on CRAN (or MRAN).

Comment: Here's the process I used. Download `rgl_0.98.13.tar.gz` from `https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=234` and put it at the root of my project directory. Then run `install.packages("rgl_0.98.13.tar.gz", repos=NULL)`. Seems to have worked. Thanks!